# How to import content from WordPress.com to a self hosted WordPress installation?

Tags: import

On behalf of another, I'm trying to import content from a WordPress.com hosted site to a self-hosted installation of WordPress.com

I've exported the XML file and imported it into the new site, but it looks completely different.

The pages are all over the place and lots of the images haven't imported.

Any ideas how I can get an exact mirror?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may need install and configure a slideshow plug-in (example: under Vertical Blinds).   The shortcut "[slideshow]" in the text is what tells the plug-in to run a slideshow.

The menu items under "Our Blinds" are in a different order - if there is a custom menu, configure it under Appearance-> Menus.

You may not be able to do it 100% automated.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. Forgot about this post! All sorted and yes, you were quite right - I did need a slideshow plugin as it seems your own installation of Wordpress doesn't come with a few features that a Wordress.com hosted blog does (like their own slideshow plugin). I had to re-upload a lot of the content, but it's all working fine now!